# Easy transactions using Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, rollback

I am working on a Java app that uses Spring [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and JDBC Template classes. I have a DAO class that has 4 methods : m1() to m4(). m1 performs multiple inserts and updates on table t1, m2 on table t2, m3 on t3, etc.

The DAO methods are used as follows:

```
while(true)
{
  //process & generate data

  dao.m1(data1);
  dao.m2(data2);
  dao.m3(data3);
  dao.m4(data4);

  //sleep
}
```

I want the db operations under the 4 consecutive method calls to be atomic, either all the 4 tables are updated successfully or none are. So, if there is an error while performing operations in m3(), i want to rollback all the changes(updates & inserts) performed in m2 & m1.

So does spring let you do it the following way ?

```
while (true)
{
  //process & generate data

  transaction = TransactionManager.createNewTransaction();

  transaction.start()

  try
  {
    dao.m1(data1);
    dao.m2(data2);
    dao.m3(data3);
    dao.m4(data4);
  }
  catch(DbUpdateException e)
  {
    transaction.rollBack();
  }

  transaction.end();

  // sleep
```

}

or are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For completeness, the programmatic solution would be:

```
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

public setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
  this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
}

...

while (true) {

  transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
      try {
        dao.m1(data1);
        dao.m2(data2);
        dao.m3(data3);
        dao.m4(data4);
      } catch(DbUpdateException e) {
        status.setRollbackOnly();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes Spring allows you to [programmatically control transactions](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html).

Personally I prefer [declarative transactions](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html) using annotations, which goes like this:

```
public void runBatchJob() {
  while (true) {
    // generate work
    doWork(unitOfWork);
  }
}

@Transactional
private void doWork(UnitOfWork work) {
  dao.m1(data1);
  dao.m2(data2);
  dao.m3(data3);
  dao.m4(data4);
}
```

where the DAO functions are defined:

```
@Transactional
public void m1(Data data) {
  ...
}
```

This requires in your *applicationContext.xml*:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Declarative transactions can be declared to require a transaction, require a new transaction, support transactions, etc. Rollback will occur when a block annotated with `@Transactional` throws a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: I don't believe you need to annotate the m1,m2,etc as @Transactional. If any throws an exception, everything already completed by doWork will be rolled back.

Comment: You don't need to in this context, no. But if they are doing updates, you should annotate them as requiring transactions, otherwise you may find yourself doing non-transactional updates if you call them outside the doWork() context.

Comment: Does the @Transactional annotation do anything when applied to a private method?

Comment: Yes, private isn't as private as it used to be. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put those calls inside a method and specify your transactions [declaratively](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html).

You don't need to add that code - Spring can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can handle this all for you by using @Transactional as explained or in XML if you'd prefer.

The import thing to get right is the type of  **Transaction Propagation** you want which all depends on your application.

By default a transaction will be started if one doesn't exist, and will re-use an existing transaction if one has already been started.  This is the behavior you want if you want all 4 DAOs to be atomic.

Put @Transactional on a class which will manage the DAO methods called (MyService) - anything below this layer will now take part in that transaction boundary.

i.e:

```
@Transactional
public void m1(Data data) {
 ...
}

@Transactional
public void m2(Data data) {
 ...
}
```

Doing this in code is completely unnecessary.

See [here for more info](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation)